# Not able to understand why the angles for drawing star using Python's turtle module is

Tags: python, graphics, geometry, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The turtle module uses commands like **fd** (forward) & **bk** (back) for movement and **rt** (right) & **lt** (left) for turning. Most programs I have done, have intuitive angles to turn by.

[image]

I tried to draw 2 types of stars (through trial and error). The 1st one is 144 (720 / 5) degrees. Why are the angles for the second star 126 and 54 degrees?

[image]

Appreciate any help.

```
import turtle as t

t.pensize(5)

for i in range(5):
  t.fd(100)
  t.lt(54)
  t.fd(100)
  t.rt(126)
```

Comment: _"Why are the angles for the second star 126 and 54 degrees?"_ Because they are the angles in that shape you've chosen. This is a geometry question, not a programming question

Comment: (126° - 54°) × 5

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pentagram image (that also contains the inner lines) from your question or [[Wikipedia]: Pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram) (chosen that particular example, but it applies to the generic case) one can see that a star (its outer contour) can be actually looked at:
**the legs of *N* equal isosceles triangles (oriented outwards), each sharing its base with a unique edge of an *N* sided regular polygon**.
Therefore, here are some characteristics of a star:

1. Number of vertices (number of isosceles triangles and sides of the polygon - *N*)
2. Edge (how big the star is)
3. Vertex angle (how sharp its vertices are)

   - Together with the edge, this determines the regular polygon side length
4. Position

So, a star is also a polygon consisting of ***2 * N*** equal sides (*N* - number of vertices) with alternating angles: vertex angle, outer angle (which can be calculated from the above)

Now, the way the 2 stars in the question were drawn is totally different:

- Pentagram: it's a special 5 vertices star. Due to its vertex angle (36°) and special relationships between angles (72°, 108°) in regular pentagon, its "shoulders" (if you will) are located on the same line (axis), and can be drawn (inner lines included) by only 5 lines. For each number of vertices (***N >= 5***, as it would be an equilateral triangle or square for *3* or *4*) there's such a special star (check below for *6*), whose (vertex) angle is `abs(720 / N - 180)`
- The other star can't be drawn as the pentagram. Also, the reason why you got it right is just a coincidental relationship between the vertex and outer angle (their sum is 180°). When drawing segments with [[Python.Docs]: turtle - Turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#module-turtle), if you want the current segment and the next one to have *alpha*° between them, you have to turn (left or right) by **(180 - *alpha*)°**

I created a small (generic, I'd say) example able to draw different stars (based on their properties).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math
import random
import sys
import turtle


def draw_star(vertices, edge, vertex_angle, center=(0, 0), rotation=0, text=None, verbose=False):
    '''
    - Isosceles triangle:
        - Base angle: (180 - vertex_angle) / 2
    - Regular polygon:
        - Angle: (vertices - 2) * 180 / vertices
    - Outer angle: 360 - Regular polygon angle - 2 * Isosceles triangle base angle
    '''
    out_angle = vertex_angle + 360 / vertices

    va_2 = math.radians(vertex_angle / 2)
    ho = edge * math.cos(va_2)
    side_2 = edge * math.sin(va_2)
    rad = ho + side_2 / math.tan(math.pi / vertices)
    if verbose:
        print("Star: vertices: {:d}, edge: {:d}, vertex angle: {:.3f} (out angle: {:.3f}), center: ({:d}, {:d}), radius: {:.3f}, rotation: {:.3f}{:s}".format(
            vertices, edge, vertex_angle, out_angle, *center, rad, rotation, ", text: '{:s}'".format(text) if text else ""))
    turtle.penup()
    #turtle.goto(center)
    #turtle.write("({:d}, {:d})".format(*center))
    rot = math.pi / 2 - math.radians(rotation)
    turtle.goto(center[0] - rad * math.cos(rot), center[1] + rad * math.sin(rot))
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.setheading(270 - vertex_angle / 2 + rotation)
    for _ in range(vertices):
        turtle.forward(edge)
        turtle.right(180 - out_angle)
        turtle.forward(edge)
        turtle.left(180 - vertex_angle)
    if text:
        turtle.write(text)


def test_stars():
    distance = 180
    offsetx = 0
    offsety = 0
    edge = 80
    stars = (
        (5, edge, 54, (distance + offsetx, distance + offsety), 0, "Yours"),
        (6, edge, 60, (-distance + offsetx, distance + offsety), 0, "David"),
        (5, edge, 36, (-distance + offsetx, -distance + offsety), 0, "Pentagram"),
        (10, edge, 30, (distance + offsetx, -distance + offsety), 0, ""),
    )
    rot = 180
    for star in stars:
        turtle.pencolor((random.randint(0, 0xFF), random.randint(0, 0xFF), random.randint(0, 0xFF)))
        draw_star(*star[:3], center=star[3], rotation=star[4], text=star[5], verbose=1)
        if rot and (star[0] % 2 == 1):
            turtle.pencolor((random.randint(0, 0xFF), random.randint(0, 0xFF), random.randint(0, 0xFF)))
            draw_star(*star[:3], center=star[3], rotation=star[4] + rot, text=star[5] + " {:d}".format(rot) if star[5] else "", verbose=1)


def test_centered_stars(var_edge=True):
    vertices = 7
    edge = 20 if var_edge else 80
    vertex_angle = 70 if var_edge else 30
    count = 15 if var_edge else 10
    rot = 0
    turtle.hideturtle()
    for i in range(count):
        draw_star(vertices, edge + (5 * i if var_edge else 0), vertex_angle, rotation=rot + (0 if var_edge else 5 * i), verbose=1)
    turtle.showturtle()


def main(*argv):
    turtle.title("SO 75268563")
    turtle.speed(speed=0)
    turtle.setup(width=0.5, height=0.66, startx=None, starty=None)
    turtle.mode(mode="standard")
    turtle.colormode(cmode=0xFF)
    turtle.pensize(3)
    test_stars()
    #test_centered_stars(var_edge=0)
    print("Click on drawing window to exit...")
    turtle.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075268563]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Star: vertices: 5, edge: 80, vertex angle: 54.000 (out angle: 126.000), center: (180, 180), radius: 121.270, rotation: 0.000, text: 'Yours'
> Star: vertices: 5, edge: 80, vertex angle: 54.000 (out angle: 126.000), center: (180, 180), radius: 121.270, rotation: 180.000, text: 'Yours 180'
> Star: vertices: 6, edge: 80, vertex angle: 60.000 (out angle: 120.000), center: (-180, 180), radius: 138.564, rotation: 0.000, text: 'David'
> Star: vertices: 5, edge: 80, vertex angle: 36.000 (out angle: 108.000), center: (-180, -180), radius: 110.111, rotation: 0.000, text: 'Pentagram'
> Star: vertices: 5, edge: 80, vertex angle: 36.000 (out angle: 108.000), center: (-180, -180), radius: 110.111, rotation: 180.000, text: 'Pentagram 180'
> Star: vertices: 10, edge: 80, vertex angle: 30.000 (out angle: 66.000), center: (180, -180), radius: 140.999, rotation: 0.000
> Click on drawing window to exit...
>
> Done.
> ```

And the drawing window:

[image: Img0]

**Notes**:

- *draw_star*:

  - Draws a star by going to the left
  - Play with different values for to see some interesting shapes:

    - Note that for some values results might not be expected ones (*e.g.* vertex angles higher than 90°)
- The examples contain your star (drawn the right way), a couple of well known ones and another (dummy) one. Odd vertices stars are also drawn 180° rotated

Also displaying centered stars output (for visual effect only):

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]